# headerTintColor ignored for back button in iOS15 (react-navigation v5)

Tags: ios, react-native, react-navigation

The value `headerTintColor` for the back button is being ignored in iOS 15 and instead uses the system standard blue color.  The Title and Header Right buttons still respect the value that I pass in.  I am using react-navigation v5 and I am trying to avoid upgrading to v6 right now, if I can avoid it. (And I don't know if this is happening in v6 or not?).  This occurs on both the device and the simulator.

iOS 15 (via Simulator):
[screenshot from iOS 15 showing blue-colored back button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BB4YY.png)

iOS <= 14 (via Simulator):
[screenshot from iOS 13 showing white colored back button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Z78e.png)

```
 <Stack.Navigator
      initialRouteName="EventList"
      screenOptions={{gestureEnabled: true}}>
      <Stack.Screen
        name="EventListScreen"
        component={EventTabs}
        options={({navigation}) => ({
          title: parametersBand.APP_NAME,
          headerTintColor: colors.NAV_TEXT_COLOR,
          headerStyle: styles.navBar,
          headerTitleStyle: styles.navBarTextStyle,
          headerTitleAllowFontScaling: false,
          headerRight: () => (
            <HeaderRightContainer>
              <HeaderRightButton
                onPress={() =>
                  analytics()
                    .logEvent('extras')
                    .then(() => navigation.navigate('Extras'))
                }
                hitSlop={hitSlop}>
                <FontAwesome name="bars" style={styles.navBarButtonHamburger} />
              </HeaderRightButton>
            </HeaderRightContainer>
          ),
          headerBackAllowFontScaling: false,
          headerBackTitle: null,
          headerBackTitleVisible: false,
          backgroundColor: colors.PRIMARY,
          borderBottomWidth: 0,
        })}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="EventDetailScreen"
        component={EventDetail}
        options={({route, navigation}) => ({
          title: route.params.event.title,
          headerTintColor: colors.NAV_TEXT_COLOR,
          headerStyle: styles.navBar,
          headerTitleStyle: styles.navBarTextStyle,
          headerTitleAllowFontScaling: false,
          headerRight: () => (
            <HeaderRightContainer>
              <HeaderRightButton
                onPress={() =>
                  analytics()
                    .logEvent('setlist', {
                      event: `${route.params.event.YYYYMMDD} ${route.params.event.altName}`,
                    })
                    .then(() =>
                      showBrowser(
                        navigation,
                        route.params.event.setlistURL,
                        parametersBand.SETLIST_TITLE,
                      ),
                    )
                }
                hitSlop={hitSlop}>
                <HeaderRightButtonText
                  style={styles.navBarButtonRight}
                  allowFontScaling={false}>
                  Setlist
                </HeaderRightButtonText>
              </HeaderRightButton>
            </HeaderRightContainer>
          ),
          headerBackAllowFontScaling: false,
          headerBackTitle: null,
          headerBackTitleVisible: false,
          backgroundColor: colors.PRIMARY,
          borderBottomWidth: 0,
        })}
      />
</Stack.Navigator>
```

Has anyone else encountered and fixed this yet?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you fixed this by now but just in case anyone else runs into this, as I just did.

The tint color for the back button is handled by the theme so you can override `theme.colors.primary` to change the tint color for the button and title text.

```js
<NavigationContainer theme={{
  ...DefaultTheme,
  colors: {
    ...DefaultTheme.colors,
    primary: 'custom color here'
  }}
>
  {...}
</NavigationContainer>
```